# Is there a way to get a list or json of all the subreddits using the api?

Tags: reddit

I've been looking at the API methods and couldn't find one that would return a json with all the subreddits.  Or is the only way to do this is by scraping reddit.com/reddits?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `.json` to the end of the URL: http://www.reddit.com/reddits.json

Comment: It doesn’t because you have to paginate using `limit` (up to 100, default is 25) and `after` (here, `t5_` followed by the id of the last element).

Comment: How to get list of subreddits subscribe by user?